# Sql server Query need to calculate YTD utilization

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to fetch the utilization percentage from table using sql query.For which i need to take the sum of previous month  utilization percentage value  to current month.

For example.

For calculating  feb utilization% value i need to take sum of 
jan(utilization % + feb utilization %)

For Mar utilization %  =(jan+feb+ mar)
For Dec utilization % =Jan+feb-------To + dec.

Comment: Are you sure you the need the sum of the previous months for the same year or average? And what about January, does it stay 0%?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: the sum of two percentages wont give you the average percentage? are you sure you want the sum? also add some sample data

Comment: yes from same year . Jan to dec value already in table.I need to fetch the data in above format

Comment: jan  =80.5  ,feb =85.5 ,mar=83.5.    Mar=80.5+85.5+83.5  .Like Dec=Jan 
 +feb ---+ Dec.

Comment: How your table is designed? The other month columns are in null or zeroes? This could radically change the approach at your problem

Comment: each month have value in table.But in the final query result the calculation should be like above

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear,anyhow the solution is given below

```
SELECT SUM(YourColumnName)
    FROM TableName Where Condition;
```

**For Ex:**

```
Select sum(utilizationPercentage)
from utilizationTable 
WHERE Months BETWEEN ’JAN’ AND ’DYNAMIC VALUE’;
```

If u select March means pass that value to your sql query and get the result